# finding parabola equation

Tags: analytic-geometry

The centers of all circles which tangent to a circle $P(2R,0)$ with radius $R$ and to the line
$x=-t$ is a Canonical parabola.
Need to find the equation of that parabola and $t$ (by $R$).

so:
 \begin{align}&\sqrt{{{(x-2R)}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}}=R+\left| x+t\right|\\ &\Leftrightarrow{{(x-2R)}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}={{x}^{2}}+2tx+{{t}^{2}}+{{R}^{2}}+2R\left| x+t\right|\\ &\Leftrightarrow{{x}^{2}}+4{{R}^{2}}-4Rx+{{y}^{2}}={{x}^{2}}+2tx+{{t}^{2}}+{{R}^{2}}+2R\left| x+t\right|\end{align}

but how can i get to the answers:

$t=R$, $y^2=8RX$?

Comment: Can you post the equation of the circle $P(2R,0)$?

Comment: Does all other circles have radius $R$ or it can vary?